# ngx-datatable is not rendering in my component.html

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using angular 5.0 in my project and tried to use I am also using bootstrap css in angular-cli but not material

```
<ngx-datatable
        [rows]="rows"
        [columns]="columns">
      </ngx-datatable>
```

but after installing and importing module I am unable to see grid rendered on my page.

```
export class AppComponent{

rows = [
    { name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
    { name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
    { name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
  ];
  columns = [
    { prop: 'name' },
    { name: 'Gender' },
    { name: 'Company' }
  ];
}
```

and module.ts

```
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    NgxDatatableModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: APIHeaderInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    SlimLoadingBarService,
    ToastsManager,
    ToasterService,
    ToastOptions

  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `prop` casing is wrong modify it as below,

```
columns = [
        { name: 'Name', prop: 'name' },
        { name: 'Gender', prop : 'gender' },
        { name: 'Company', prop : 'company' }
  ];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for update i copied this code from their demo website but even after making the changes which u have suggested still not getting grid rendered may be missing something

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: i am on skype rahul.antilog or gmail rahuljain1248@gmail.com

Comment: the table is rendering once I declare in app.component.html since inside app.module.ts I have declared it but when I am trying to display table inside sub module of project it is not rendering